# How to boot Ubuntu from my SD card?

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, boot, sd-card

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 onto a micro SD card for an embedded device. However via the SD card adapter I have, I would like to boot it up on my laptop for development purposes. The SD has 32gb flash storage, so I want to put programs on it, etc, developing on my laptop then put it back on the embedded device.

I have Windows 7 on my system; here is what I see when I open the SD card folder from My Computer:

[image: 1]

Clicking on any of the files doesn't magically boot the Ubuntu unfortunately =(

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Embedded Devices are typically `ARM` processors, not x86 - so more likely than not you cannot do what you are looking to (you may be able to emulate an ARM processor using QEMU though... I can't speak to that really).  Did you install the [Ubuntu ARM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM) edition to the uSD?

Comment: _VERY_ important point nerdwaller :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Laptop has the ability to boot from an SD-Card - most do, but some Thinkpad models don't, afaik - you need to restart the computer and when the first Logo shows up (usually the manufacturers', like Dell or Lenovo) theres a Hint on how to select the boot medium, which reads something like "Press F12 to select boot medium" or something similar.

Press that button and select the SD-Card, then it should boot.

Otherwise, go into the Bios and change the boot medium priority to set the SD card as highest, then the Laptop will always try to boot from the SD card, and fall back to the original hard drive if it cant find a bootmedium there.